# Error returned when trying to call my local webservice using springboot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a local hosted webservice. The controller when returns a single String value it works fine. But whenever I try to return either the list or a particular Object, it returns Whitelabel error page with error code 500. Below is the error when I try to return list.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

I get below error when I try to access a particular object, say /topic/1.
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No converter found for return value of type: class com.spring.rest.topic.Topic

Note: 1.I see that jackson dependency is added by spring-boot-starter-web dependency. So not required to add again in pom.xml.
2.My Pojo class, Topic, has public getters for all attributes.
Below are my classes:

Topic.java(Pojo class):

```
package com.spring.rest.topic;

public class Topic {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Topic(){

    }

    public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

TopicController.java(Controller class):

```
package com.spring.rest.topic;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TopicController {

    @Autowired              //this annotation tells spring to inject an object for the dependency.
    private TopicService service;

    @RequestMapping("/topics")  //spring mvc casts the list to json.
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){
        return service.getAllTopics();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/topic/{id}")
    public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id){
        return service.getTopic(id);
    }
}
```

TopicService.java(Service class):

```
package com.spring.rest.topic;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

//in spring, a service class is of singleton scope.
@Service
public class TopicService {

    private List<Topic> topics = Arrays.asList(new Topic("1","SpringMVC","Using spring mvc"),
            new Topic("2","RESTful API","Using REST top create a micro services"));

    public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){
        return topics;
    }

    public Topic getTopic(String id){
        /*Topic topic = new Topic();*/
        for(Topic topic : getAllTopics()){
            if(topic.getId().equals(id)){
                return topic;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>spring.java.rest.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringRest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a json mapper to your dependency tree, like `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`'s `jackson-databind`. i.e.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It worked after adding the dependency. But I checked and could find the same dependency is already added by the <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>, that I have in my pom.xml. Does changing the version did the trick?

Comment: Yes, Version did the trick! :(, but its difficult to solve such issues

Comment: Same issue after adding the depedency :- pom.xml :
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>